# Change text in bold in angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular.js application in which I display some elements in a table. 
In those elements, I have a name and in some case, I change it to add `<b>` and `</b>` to have it in bold. But it's displayed like a string and not like HTML code.

So I would replace all the text on the page between the `<b>` and the `</b>` with the same text but in bold.

I try to do this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(nameFilter, "g");
e.name = e.name.replace(pattern, '<span class="highlighted">' + nameFilter + '</span>');
```

But it's always displayed like a string.

Do you know what do to have the text in bold?

Comment: For that you need to use **trustAsHtml** using **$sce** provider. Can you post your template as well to understand your question better?

Comment: The template is pretty difficult but I just have a table with a ng-repeat to display the name of all components in a column. And in some components, I changed the name to add the bold signs. Can you share an example of trustAsHtml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm adding the code for **$sce.trustAsHtml** example scenario below as you have requested in the comment section. Also please check [this plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/TdZLnh4qOwNoc0sH) for working example.

**Template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in empList">
    <td><span ng-bind-html="emp.name | trustAsHtml"></span></td>
    <td>{{emp.dept}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.empList = [
    { name: '<b>Test 1</b>', dept: 'Finance'},
    { name: '<b>Test 2</b>', dept: 'Development'},
    { name: '<b>Test 3</b>', dept: 'Testing'},
    { name: '<b>Test 4</b>', dept: 'DBA'}
  ];
});

app.filter('trustAsHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return $sce.trustAsHtml;
}]);
```

***Note:*** Do not forget to inject **'ngSanitize'** into module as shown in the plunker example.